# variable or field ' ...' declared void

Tags: arduino, adc

I'm working on an ADC ATSAM3x8e arduino due board. I'm trying to write new `.h` and `.cpp` files.

How do I create a datatype like same as instance name of the  processor?
Example: In ADC of the processor the datatype name like as `ADC* p_Adc`, In EMAC the datatype like as `Emac* p_emac`

I've already written one program; the error is showing like:

```
error 1. Variable or field ' function name' declared void 
error 2. 'ADC' was not declared in the scope  (ADC is datatype)
error 3. 'p_adc'  was not declared in the scope
```

My Header file contains:

```
void ADC_Mode_register(ADC* p_adc,uint32_t value);
void ADC_control_register(ADC* p_adc,uint32_t value);
```

Comment: google "typedef struct" and/or "typedef union"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is missing the definitions and declarations for `ADC` which very likely should be a `struct` or at least `union`, such that `ADC*` appears to be a pointer to `ADC`.

For Example:

Your project is supposed to have something like this:

```
typedef struct stADC_config{
    unsigned int uiChannels;
    bool bEnDisCtrl;
    uint8_t uCdataDescriptor[8];
    long lAdc_count;
}ADC;
```